# Eliminating duplicates in a tuple python

Tags: python

I have a tuple containing duplicate items and different value for each item. I want to create a new tuple that contain this list with unique items and the total value pair. Was wondering if there's an efficient way to do this. I'm really new to python and not sure how to approach this. A pseudo code would help alot.

```
tuple1 = [(3, 4), (2, 4), (3, 7), (2, 1), (3, 8)]
```

Want to create tuple2

```
tuple2 = [(3, 19), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: What have you tried? I'd say these tuple elements look very muck like key-value pairs, so I'd use a `dict` keyed by the first element, while adding up values.

Comment: i've used two for loops to iterate through tuple1 and add the value with the same key at index [0] and add it to a new list. I want it to stay as a tuple not convert it to a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just iterate and sum

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for (u,v) in tuple1:
...     d[u]+=v
... 
>>> print(*d.items())
(3, 19) (2, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an intermediate temporary dictionary, but if you don't want to do that, you can use `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter` in a nested forloop.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

tuple1 = [(3,4),(2,4),(3,7),(2,1),(3,8)]
first = itemgetter(0)
tuple2 = [(k, sum(item[1] for item in tups_to_sum))
        for k, tups_to_sum in groupby(sorted(tuple1, key=first), key=first)]
```

**Output:**

```
[(2, 5), (3, 19)]
```

Comment: This takes O(n log n) time because of sorting; the problem can be solved in O(n) time by a one-pass algorithm (see abc's answer).

Answer (score 1):

basically you can use this:

```
[(i[0],sum([j[1] for j in tuple1 if j[0]==i[0]])) for i in tuple1]
```

although if you run this you'll find out that this code generates duplicates, in other words:

```
[(3, 19), (2, 5), (3, 19), (2, 5), (3, 19)]
```

here you can either remove the duplicates or define the function unique as follows:

```
def unique(list1): 
    unique_list = [] 
    for x in list1: 
        if x[0] not in unique_list: 
            unique_list.append(x[0]) 
    return unique_list
```

finally you can change your list to this:

```
[(i,sum([j[1] for j in tuple1 if j[0]==i])) for i in unique(tuple1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner:

```
tuple2 = [(first, sum([vv for kk,vv in tuple1 if kk==first])) for first in set([k for k,_ in tuple1])]
```

This will use a set of the first element of tuples from `tuple1`. Then sum up the second elements, returning a list of tuples.

Comment: This is O(n^2) in the worst case; the problem can be solved in O(n) time by a one-pass algorithm (see abc's answer).